# How to add external jar

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, geoip

I have added an external jar(for jar Visit [jarlink](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.maxmind.geoip2%22%20AND%20a%3a%22geoip2%22)) on my java project but I do not have all features of that library.

I added jar following this way click left on my `project and properties->Java Build Path->Libraries tabs->Add External Jar`.

Is this the right way ? or I am doing it wrong?

for example link Visit mkyong.com/java/java-find-location-using-ip-address I am trying to do this example .I have added that jar on my project but some imports do not work

I have added geoip2-0.7.0.jar (import com.maxmind.*) this import is working but (import com.maxmind.geoip.regionName;)  this import is not working

errors : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ServerLocation
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ServerLocation`enter code here`
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more

Comment: "I do not have all features of that library" <-- what do you mean? Why don't you use a build system such as gradle, for instance?

Comment: In what? **eclipse IDE** for a **maven** project? Add key words. Maven itself has a `pom.xml` with `<dependency>` for every jar.

Comment: Are you using the correct jar? Are there .class files inside?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-find-location-using-ip-address/       I am trying to do this example .I have added that jar on my project but some imports do not work

Comment: Please post the exact errors you are encountering.

Comment: I have added some informations

Answer (score 0):

The most natural way to do this, is to create a `lib` folder, put your libs in there, then add the JARs to the build path.

If you're using Maven, you just need to specify the dependency groupId and artifactId, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

To add external jar,

if you use eclipse find out [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29).

If you generate a project using maven, Add a dependency in pom.xml. Find sample  [here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_external_dependencies.htm)